# Removing newlines in Python

Tags: python, newline

I have a sequence file begining with `>` and afterwards a lot of letters followed by newlines and then again `>`. I am able to extract the line begining with `>` and the letter lines in to two different variables, when there are no newlines, but I does not work if there are any newlines. My question is, how can I, in my script, remove these newlines?

Answer (score 3):

Your question's pretty unclear, but if you simply need to remove all newlines, use `str.replace` (`replace("\n", "")`)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string `'blah'` containing newlines:

```
# Replaces all newline characters with nothing
blah = blah.replace("\n", "")
```

PS: Once you have found an answer which works for you, click the tick next to the answer to 'accept' it (helping others with your problem know which solution works).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

You can always replace any sequence in a string by using `replace`. In this case you'd do something like

```
foo.replace("\n", "")
```

If you're just trying to remove the newline from the end of a bunch of lines, you're better off using `strip`.

```
foo.strip()
```

What you probably want to do is this:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as fh:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fh.readlines()[1:-1]]
```

That will open the file, then read each line (without the newline) into the variable `lines`, and ignore the first and last lines.

Comment: I do it like:
file = open('somefile', 'r')
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
I have also tried with replace, but they do not work for me. I still have problems.